# left-button in navigation not show correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show a red cycle and a text inside it in navigation.

```
self.btnNewUpdates.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
```

but this line of my code not work correctly. I change the width 20 to 30 or 10 or any value, it doesn't change correctly:

[image]

my code:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var btnNewUpdates: UIButton!
```

....

```
self.btnNewUpdates.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
//self.btnNewUpdates.contentHorizontalAlignment = .right
//btnNewUpdates.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.btnNewUpdates.setImage(UIImage(named:"menuImg"), for: .normal)
self.btnNewUpdates.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
self.btnNewUpdates.setTitle("1000", for: .normal)
self.btnNewUpdates.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.btnNewUpdates.setNeedsLayout()
self.btnNewUpdates.layoutIfNeeded()
self.btnNewUpdates.titleLabel?.layer.cornerRadius = (self.btnNewUpdates.titleLabel?.frame.width)! / 2.0
self.btnNewUpdates.titleLabel?.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.btnNewUpdates.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -((self.btnNewUpdates.imageView?.frame.width)!-5), left: 0, bottom: 0, right: (self.btnNewUpdates.imageView?.frame.width)!)
self.btnNewUpdates.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: -(self.btnNewUpdates.titleLabel?.frame.width)!+10)
```

Comment: At what point in the View Controller lifecycle are you setting the frame?

Comment: Where do you set the button as a left navigation item? did you try without `titleEdgeInsets` and `imageEdgeInsets`?

Comment: @Ryan yes, yes but doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Where do you set the button as a left navigation item?